# Existence of solution

Tags: operator-theory

Assume that $T$ is an compact integral operator on $L^2(D)$ and let $M$ be its Hilbert norm. here $D$ is the unit conplex disk
I need a reference for the following assertion. There is a function $f$ so that $T^* T f = M^ 2 f$.

Comment: What is the Hilbert norm of an operator? Is it the operator norm?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That is.

Comment: Presumably you want $f$ which is not identically zero :)

Comment: In fact it is true by very elementary facts. $T^*T$ is a  symmetric positive compact operator on a Hilbert space. Eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a symmetric compact operator $L$ have a variational characterization: they are critical values/critical points of the Raileigh quotient $(Lx\cdot x)/(x\cdot x)$. In particular $\|L\|$ is an eigenvalue. This is elementary material that you can find in any textbook of Fun.Anal.

Comment: Please also note that generic titles such as *Existence of a solution* should be avoided. Check the guidelines about "how to ask".

Answer (score 3):

Since an answer has already be given, let me leave the following longer but more elementary approach as a complete answer rather than a sketch in a comment. I think this material is actually fairly standard and probably in a book such as Bollobas's *Linear Analysis* or Kadison+Ringrose's *Introduction to the Theory of Operator Algebras* (although I am going from very hazy memories which may be mistaken).

As Dieter Kadelka, points out, this is true in greater generality/abstraction.

> **Proposition 1.** Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and let $M=\Vert T\Vert$. Then $M^2$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $T^*T$. (See e.g. Wikipedia for the definition.)
> $\newcommand{\hnorm}[1]{{\Vert#1\Vert}_H}\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$

*Proof.* By definition of $M$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $H$ with $\hnorm{x_n}=1$ for all $n$ and $\hnorm{Tx_n}\nearrow M$. Now observe:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hnorm{T^*Tx_n -M^2x_n}^2
& = \ip{T^*Tx_n- M^2x_n}{T^*Tx_n- M^2x_n} \\
& = \hnorm{T^*Tx_n}^2 - 2M^2 \ip{T^*Tx_n}{x_n} + M^4 \\
& = \hnorm{T^*Tx_n}^2 - 2M^2 \hnorm{Tx_n}^2 + M^4 \\
& \leq 2\Vert T^*T\Vert^2 -2 M^2\hnorm{Tx_n}^2
\end{aligned}
$$
We have $\Vert T^*T\Vert \leq M^2$ (actually, equality holds but we don't need this) and $\hnorm{Tx_n} \to M$ as $n\to\infty$. It follows that
$\hnorm{T^*Tx_n-M^2x_n}^2$ is bounded above by something which converges to zero as $n\to\infty$.
**Q.E.D.**

> **Lemma 2.** Let $K$ be a compact operator on a Banach space $X$ and suppose $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $K$. Then $\lambda$ is actually an eigenvalue of $K$.

*Proof.* By assumption there is a sequence of norm-one vectors in $X$, say $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$, such that $\Vert Kx_n- \lambda x_n\Vert \to 0$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(x_{n(j)})_{j\geq 1}$ which converges to some $y\in X$; since each $x_{n(j)}$ has norm one, so does $y$.  Then $Ky-\lambda y = \lim_j Kx_{n(j)} - \lambda x_{n(j)} = 0$.
**Q.E.D.**

> **Corollary 3.** Let $T$ be a compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $M=\Vert T\Vert$. Then $M^2$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*T$.

*Proof.* Since $T$ is compact so is $T^*T$. Apply Proposition 1 and Lemma 2.
**Q.E.D.**

(Note that Corollary 3 is one possible starting point for the standard proof of the spectral theorem which Dieter Kadelka uses for his solution.)

Answer (score 2):

A direct reference for this result may be difficult to find. Actually its a direct consequence of the spectral decomposition theorem found in most functional analysis books, f.i. Dunford/Schwartz: Linear Operators II.

You can replace $L^2(D)$ by any Hilbert space $H$. With $T$ also $U := T^* T$ is a compact operator, which is self-adjoint and with $\lambda \geq 0$ for any Eigenvalue of $U$ (since $0 \leq \langle Tx,Tx \rangle = \langle x,Ux \rangle = \langle x,\lambda x \rangle = \lambda \langle x,x \rangle$). Let $\sigma(U) \subset [0,\infty)$ be the (compact) spectrum of $U$. Since $U$ is in addition self-adjoint there is a spectral decomposition of $U$ in the form
$$Ux = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(U)} \lambda P_\lambda x$$
with $P_\lambda$ the (finite dimensional, if $\lambda > 0$) projection on the orthogonal Eigenspaces of $U$ corresponding to Eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $M^2$ be the largest Eigenvalue of $U$ and $f$ be an Eigenvector corresponding to Eigenvalue $M^2$, Then $Uf = M^2 f$ and further $\|T\|^2 = \sup_{x \in H \colon \|x\| \leq 1} \langle Tx,Tx \rangle = \sup_{x \in H \colon \|x\| \leq 1} \langle x,Ux \rangle \leq M^2$, thus replacing $x$ by $f$ even $\|T\|^2 = M^2$.

Comment: The spectral theorem is overkill. One of the usual approaches to proving the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators on Hilbert space, is to start with the observation that for $T=T^\ast \in B(H)$ at least one of $\Vert T\Vert$ or $-\Vert T\Vert$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $T$, and for compact operators approximate eigenvalues are eigenvalues